# Como fazer quebrar os filhos alinhados com flexbox?

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

Como faço para que os filhos 4 5 6 fiquem abaixo da 1 2 3 quando o site estiver em modo tablet ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <title>flexbox</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <style type="text/css">
   
   *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
   }

   body{
    background:#dfdfdf;
   }
        /* MOBILE */
   @media(max-width:649px){
    .container{
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:column;
    }

    .container article{
     margin-bottom:1em;
     height:250px;
     border:2px solid black;
     color:white;
     font-family:arial;
     font-weight:bold;
    }

    .container article:nth-child(1){
     background: black;
     
    }

    .container article:nth-child(2){
     background:#111;
     
    }

    .container article:nth-child(3){
     background:#222;
     
    }

    .container article:nth-child(4){
     background:#333;
     
    }
   }

        /* TABLET */
   @media(min-width:650px){
    .container{
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:row;
    }

    .container article{
     height:200px;
     
     color:white;
     font-family:arial;
     font-weight:bold;
     margin-right:0.5em;
    }

    .container article:nth-child(1){
    flex:1;     
    background: black;
    border:2px solid #222;
    }
    
    .container article:nth-child(2){
    flex:1;
    background:#111;
    }
    
    .container article:nth-child(3){
    flex:1;
    background:#222;
    }

    .container article:nth-child(4){
    flex:1;
    background:#333;
    }

    .container article:nth-child(5){
    flex:1;
    background:#444;
    }

    .container article:nth-child(6){
    flex:1;
    background:#555;
    margin-right:0;
    }
   }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

 <section class="container">
  <article>01</article>
  <article>02</article>
  <article>03</article>
  <article>04</article>
  <article>05</article>
  <article>06</article>
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode combinar as propriedades flex-direction e fle-wrap para obter o resultado que você quer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
 <title>flexbox</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <style type="text/css">
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  body {
   background: #dfdfdf;
  }

  /* TABLET */
  @media(min-width:650px) {
   .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
   }

   .container article {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 1rem;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #555;
   }
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <section class="container">
  <article>01</article>
  <article>02</article>
  <article>03</article>
  <article>04</article>
  <article>05</article>
  <article>06</article>
 </section>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]